# CloudTrail - sourceIPAddress field in CloudTrail management event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

Below is the event I received in S3 logs generated by CloudTrail:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "AID...HVRL",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::233333337:user/Administrator",
        "accountId": "233333337",
        "accessKeyId": "abcd",
        "userName": "Administrator"
    },
    "eventTime": "2019-06-26T21:49:54Z",
    "eventSource": "acm.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "GetCertificate",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "64.xx.xx.224",
    "userAgent": "aws-sdk-go/1.20.3 (go1.12.6; darwin; amd64)",
    "requestParameters": {
        "certificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:233333337:certificate/23fffff-1fff4-bfff-6fffff"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "certificateChain": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID2zCCA...ZYIQ\u003d\u003d\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDrzC......Nh7d1A6k8\u003d\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
        "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDpTC......8ilqQHRR80CEg\u003d\u003d\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    },
    "requestID": "55600533-985c-11e9-8a21-a3d9a1ca5215",
    "eventID": "a50a8e95-972a-44aa-9c74-ddf59b12ccc8",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "285774445527"
}
```

after submitting AWS SDK request to AWS Cert manager from my Mac laptop,

but,

`ifconfig` on my MAC laptop **does not** show `64.xx.xx.224`

but the event log has

`"sourceIPAddress"` as `"64.xx.xx.224"`

---

What does `sourceIPAddress` indicate  in this event?

Comment: Were you doing it from a corporate network? What is displayed if you go to http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It doesn't give the IP address from your referred link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address is the one from which the request originated, as seen by AWS.

Computers on a network typically have a local IP address (192.x or 10.x). When requests exit to the Internet, they will "appear" to come from the IP address associated with the router gateway. So, all traffic within a company will typically appear to come from the same IP address. Even traffic on a home network will go out on one public IP address.

The `UserAgent` does indicate that you used the GO SDK on a Mac, so it probably is your request. Therefore, trust it that your requests do "appear" to be coming from that IP address.

Comment: Is this nat setup?

Comment: Yes. CloudTrail will capture the source IP as seen by Amazon servers in the public internet. NAT devices can translate your IP between private/public networks and therefore change the visible IP address. Another (completely different) way to verify this behavior is to store the requestID from your SDK call and then compare it with the CloudTrail event. They should match.